# How to add border radius to code editor from @uiw/react-codemirror library

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, codemirror

I am trying to add a simple border radius to the code editor component that comes from the @uiw/react-codemirror library. I've tried adding it into the component, as well as wrapping the code mirror component in a div, and adding the border radius to the div.

```
<CodeMirror
                value={solution}
                height="250px"
                borderRadius='16px'
                extensions={[javascript()]}
                theme={dracula}
                editable={false}
                className="solution-code-editor"
              />
```

Comment: `borderRadius` property would work only if CodeMirror component supported such input. Have you tried to add the border-radius to `.solution-code-editor` in CSS?

Comment: @metodribic I have, but that doesn't seem to work as well.